# I am using python 2.7 in windows 10 and i am getting name error in juptyr notebook how can i solve this problem?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5LYA.png)
As you can see in the image there is a name error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30UdW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first cell was not executed yet. It has "In [ ]". Just run it before you run the second one.